# Que comando puedo usar para averiguar si hay actualizaciones en el repositorio git?

Tags: linux, git, shell, shell-script

Estoy haciendo un proyecto de tipo shell-scrip y necesito saber si existe algún comando para averiguar si hay actualizaciones en mi repositorio en gitlab. Ya que debo informar si se necesita hacer un git pull.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Primero tienes que hacer un `git fetch` para traer tus cambios sin mezclarlos con tu repositorio local.

Luego puedes hacer un script como el siguiente:

```
#!/bin/bash

UPSTREAM=${1:-'@{u}'}
LOCAL=$(git rev-parse @)
REMOTE=$(git rev-parse "$UPSTREAM")
BASE=$(git merge-base @ "$UPSTREAM")

if [ $LOCAL = $REMOTE ]; then
    echo "Up-to-date"
elif [ $LOCAL = $BASE ]; then
    echo "Need to pull"
elif [ $REMOTE = $BASE ]; then
    echo "Need to push"
else
    echo "Diverged"
fi
```

Donde `rev-parse` te muestra el id commit que desees, y `merge-base` encuentra el mejor común ancestro entre dos commits.

Esto lo obtuve de la respuesta en [el sitio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3258243/check-if-pull-needed-in-git) en inglés: